# Flask 405 Method Error

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

Hi i'm trying to add a contact to my sqlite db although I keep getting a 405 method error. Any ideas??

my method:

```
@app.route('/addcontact/', methods=['POST'])
    def contact_add():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            g.db.execute('insert into address (surname, firstname, email, mobile),values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                     [request.form['firstname'], request.form['surname'], request.form['email']
                    , request.form['mobile']])
            g.db.commit()
            flash('New entry was successfully posted')
            return redirect(url_for('contacts')) #redirect to the contacts page
```

My html:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>Add new contact</h1>
      <form action='/addcontact/' method="post">
        <dl>
          <dt>First Name:
          <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="firstname">
          <dt>Surname:
          <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="surname">
          <dt>Email:
          <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="email">
          <dt>Mobile:
          <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="mobile">            
          <dd><input type="submit" value="Add New Contact">
        </dl>
      </form>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="/contact">List of contacts</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the GET method.

You need to add both GET and POST methods to your view. The reason is that initially, it will be the GET method that displays the form. Then after entering the items, you hit submit which then uses POST. So I will edit your code to:

```
@app.route('/addcontact/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def contact_add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        g.db.execute('insert into address (surname, firstname, email, mobile),values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                 [request.form['firstname'], request.form['surname'], request.form['email']
                , request.form['mobile']])
        g.db.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted')
        return redirect(url_for('contacts')) #redirect to the contacts page

    # If not POST, then you should render the initial form below (GET will be used)
    return render_template('form.html')
```

Comment: thanks, I've made the change you suggested and it almost works. I add the entry although it comes up with error but strangely its already inserted into the db: 
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1620, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
    BuildError: ('contacts', {}, None)

Comment: its an issue with ```return redirect(url_for('contacts'))

Answer (score -1):

Guessing:

```
request.method != 'POST'
```

so

```
print request.method
```

Comment: so do you mean if I add on a elif to the method?

Comment: I think if you use `@post` then you do not need the if test.

Comment: I haven't seen that before @post, so do you mean create a method for the post?